# Why is the following negative lookahead is not working

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
txt =  'harry potter is awsome  so is harry james potter'
pat = '\W+(?!potter)'
re.findall(pat,txt)
```

according to my understanding the the output should have been all the words that are not followed by potter that is

> ['potter', 'is', 'awsome', 'so', 'is', 'harry', 'james', 'potter']

but the actual output is

> ['harry', 'potter', 'is', 'awsome', 'so', 'is', 'harry', 'james', 'potter']

why is the pattern also matching the harry that is followed by potter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get this result:

```
[' ', ' ', '  ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```

...which is exactly what I expect.  `\W+` (note the uppercase `W`) matches one or more non-word characters, so `\W+(?!potter)` matches the whitespace between the words in your input, except when the upcoming word starts with "potter".  If I wanted to match each word that's not followed by the word "potter" I would use this regex:

```
pat = r'\b\w+\b(?!\W+potter\b)'
```

`\b` matches a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html); the first two insure that I'm matching a whole word, and the last one makes sure the upcoming word is "potter" and not a longer word that *starts* with "potter".

Notice how I used raw string (`r'...'`).  You should get in the habit of using them for all your regexes in Python.  In this case, `\b` would be interpreted as a backspace character if I had used a normal string.

Answer (score 4):

because `" potte"` doesn't match `"potter"`.

```
>>> txt = 'harry potter is awsome  so is harry james potter'
>>> pat = '(\w+)(?:\W|\Z)(?!potter)'
>>> re.findall(pat,txt)
['potter', 'is', 'awsome', 'so', 'is', 'harry', 'potter']
```

Answer (score 3):

> according to my understanding the the output should have been all the words that are not followed by potter

It does. The thing is, every word is not followed by `potter`, because every word, by definition, is followed by either whitespace or the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

txt =  txt =  'harry potter is awsome  so is harry james potter'

pat = r'\w+\b(?![\ ]+potter)'

print re.findall(pat,txt)
```